# How to generate properties in underlying class mapped to elements with x:Name attribute

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have `DataTemplate` which requires some code behind. This template contains e.g. `ListBox`with attribute `x:Name="myListBox"`. This template is located in `ResourceDictionary` which has attribute `x:Class="MyNamespace.MyClass"`. Now how could I get access from the code of `MyClass` to the `myListBox` instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
ContentPresenter contentPresenter = FindVisualChild<ContentPresenter>(myListBox);

DataTemplate yourDataTemplate = contentPresenter.ContentTemplate;

TextBox txtName= yourDataTemplate.FindName("vidList", contentPresenter) 
as TextBox ;
if (txtName!= null)
{
    // Do something with txtNamehere
}
```